# Download file to local computer via SCP while ssh connection to remote computer

Tags: ssh, terminal

I keep getting an error when trying to download a file from a remote computer when connected via SSH.

I'm using a Mac and connecting via terminal.

I type the following:

```
scp username@host : /path/to/hosts/file/host_file.txt ~/desktop
```

I then enter my password and get the following error:

```
scp: .: not a regular file
cp: cannot create regular file '/host_file.txt': permission denied
/directory/user/desktop: no such file or directory
```

Any help?

It appears to be trying to save it to a directory on the remote system but I'm not sure.

**update:

I removed space on either side of the : 
It now appears to download but I don't see anything on my desktop.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Once again confused as to how this is off topic. Helped me a great deal, has #1 Google rank, etc etc... Are people not allowed to ask server admin related questions?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Instead of

```
scp username@host : /path/to/hosts/file/host_file.txt ~/desktop
```

remove the spaces surrounding the `:`.

```
scp username@host:/path/to/hosts/file/host_file.txt ~/desktop
```

---

**Edit:**

> I keep getting an error when trying to download a file from a remote computer when connected via SSH.

**You shouldn't run the scp command when you are already sshed into the server** --- that just downloads the file from the server... to the server.

You should run the scp command directly from your mac.

Comment: thank you, then I get the following: 100% 59 0.1kb/s ...

I'm guessing this implies it downloaded but I don't see anything on my desktop.

Comment: I had thought that OSX used a case insensitive filesystem, but perhaps not. Try `ls -ld *esktop` (that's dash lower-L lower-D), and if it shows a `desktop` file and a `Desktop` directory, run `mv desktop Desktop/host_file.txt`.

Comment: When I tried that it says: 
mv: accessing 'Desktop/host_file.txt': Not a directory

Could it possibly be trying to download it to itself (the remote machine)? With a few other commands it was listing file paths on the remote machine (the server, not my computer). 

Do I need to specify my machines path? I used ~/Desktop

Comment: Are you sshed into the server? Try running the commands in a new shell window, so we can be sure they run on your mac and not on the server. You used ~/Desktop *where*?

Comment: I put ~/Desktop after the scp command while connected to the server.

I was trying to use that to download to my desktop. I tried typing out the complete file path and it says "no such file or directory"

Comment: You shouldn't run the scp command when you are already sshed into the server --- that just downloads the file from the server... to the server. You should run the command directly from your mac.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much! As you can see I'm new to this so it was confusing!

Answer (score 14):

Remove the spaces on either side of `:`

```
scp username@host:/path/to/hosts/file/host_file.txt ~/desktop
```

(to be 100% clear, I mean remove the spaces on either side of the colon character)